# Proving that a function has no repeated roots

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $\mathbb{Q} \subset F$ be a field extension.  Prove that if $f(x) \in F[x]$ is irreducible, then it has no repeated roots in any field extension of F.

as a hint we were given that a repeated root must be a roof of both $f(x)$ and its derivative.  but I'm still not really sure what to do with it.  any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hint: think about what happens if an irreducible polynomial shares a root with another polynomial.

Comment: it has to divide it.  so could we prove contrapositively,  that if a function has a repeated root in a field extension of F then f(x) is reducible because we could divide f(x) by its derivative since they share a common root.

Comment: @Sam Over a field, how can a polynomial of degree $\;n\;$ divide another polynomial of degree $\;n-1\;$ ??

Comment: it cant divide it

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ has a repeated root $\alpha$, it would be a root of $f'$ too, but $ker$ $ eval_{\alpha}=(f)$ as long as $f$ is irreducible. Then, $f|f'$ which is impossible because $deg(f)>deg(f')$ and $char(\mathbb{Q})=0$.